# How do I target an XML node to extract the value in Logic Apps?

Tags: xml, azure-logic-apps

I have a HTTP that returns some XML from an API. I want to test it for specific values, so I have set up a Condition action which contains:

```
@or(equals(body('HTTP')['job']['template_name'],'Collection'),equals(body('HTTP')['job']['template_name'],'Drop Off')
```

The XML I am doing this on looks like

```
<job>
<template_name>Collection</template_name>
<value>1212</value>
</job>
```

I believe I am using JSON targeting syntax, but I have googled high and low and can't see how to simply target the XML node. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to use xpath function, for example:

@xpath(xml(body('Http')), '/*[local-name()=\"job\" and namespace-uri()=\"http://yournamespace.com\"]/*[local-name()=\"template_name\" and namespace-uri()=\"http://yournamespace.com\"]')

To access the value of the node.

Comment: in my condition I have 

@or(
  equals(@xpath(xml(body('HTTP')), '//*[local-name()=\"template_name\"]/text()'),'Collection'),
  equals(@xpath(xml(body('HTTP')), '//*[local-name()=\"template_name\"]/text()'),'Delivery')
) 

This throws an error when I try to save the logic app: "The template is not valid: the string character '@' at position '13' is not expected." and thats the @xpath in the equals operator.... stumped...

Comment: The @ character is only needed at the beginning: @or( equals(xpath(xml(body('HTTP')), '//*[local-name()=\"template_name\"]/text()'),'Collection'), equals(xpath(xml(body('HTTP')), '//*[local-name()=\"template_name\"]/text()'),'Delivery') )

Comment: Works this solution? or you have any other problem?

Comment: This will still return the node name syntax wrapped around the value (i.e., `<node_name>value</node_name>`. How do you get the value itself?

Comment: For anyone looking to extract the value itself from XML as a string, See this post: [Logic App Xpath Output - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/93375/logic-app-xpath-output.html).